# How to put a class that has "deleted" copy ctor and assignment operator in map?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

Since I'm on a not-quite-C++11 compiler (VS 11) I'm getting a linker error about prevention of usage of copy ctor a assignment operator. All is dandy but the problem is that I can't put my class in a `std::map` where key is `uin32_t` and value is my class. I even tried `emplace`, but it does not work.

I am thinking about `std::move`ing a `unique_ptr` into a `map`, but would prefer not to redesign a container. So is there any elegant way of doing this (elegant == not like putting a dummy in a map and then placement new on the value memory :)?

Code bits are like this:

```
std::map<uint32_t, LogFileWriter> m_map;

//declared not defined 
public:

LogFileWriter(const LogFileWriter& other);  // commenting this makes emplace work
```

Comment: Can you elaborate and show us the relevant code parts? Does your map hold the objects themselves? Like `map<uint32, MyObject>`?

Comment: Can you show some code (at least the relevant declarations)? Does you class have a non-throwing move ctor and move assignment op?

Comment: "I even tried emplace, does not work." do you mean by this that your compiler's implementation of `map::emplace` is known to be buggy, or that your code using `emplace` doesn't work?

Comment: I added code , and my compiler is VS11.

Comment: @Angew no, but I thought emplace constructs object inplace, without move...

Comment: Yes, emplace should construct without a move. Can you show your code using `emplace()`? BTW, it wouldn't surprise me too much to learn of an `emplace()` bug in VS11; they certainly made a mess of `emplace()` in VS10.

Comment: @AlexFarber That's called a move constructor; I already asked about that, and it shouldn't be necessary for `emplace()`.

Comment: I understand from the question that you want a C++98 solution, don't you? But move constructor and `std::move` are C++11 only.

Comment: @FireAphis I wrote C++98++ compiler, it was edited. It means im on compiler that supports C++11 a bit, but not 100%. I specified it is VS 11

Comment: seems like this is just a VS bug/missing feature from what I can see from comments.

Comment: Still, could you show your code which uses `emplace()`? Perhaps it could be made to work.

Comment: if ( ! mymap.count(ip))
        mymap.emplace(pair<uint32_t, LogFileWriter>(source_ip, LogFileWriter(somestring+ ".log")));             tried also with make_pair , no luck

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Your call to the constructor of `pair` tries to copy/move the temporary `LogFileWriter` into the `pair`. Passing the `pair` to `emplace` can't stop that happening. Try `mymap.emplace(source_ip, somestring+".log");`

Comment: @SteveJessop yes. Quite embarrasing but that was the problem... so either make your comment in A or Ill delete Q since it is misleading. I still dont get it how emplace can split arguments appropriately to key and value, I guess it only works for 1 param ctor ?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: it doesn't split the arguments. It passes all of them to a constructor call for `std::pair<const K,V>`, so yes each of `K` and `V` must have a 1-arg constructor.

Comment: cute special case, but what if my key had 42 param ctor and my value 47 param ctor ?

Comment: @SteveJessop I guestimated it after a lot of work to be emplace with piecewise_construct tag, so if anybody is reading this in the future... have fun piecewise_constructing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `if ( ! mymap.count(ip)) mymap.emplace(pair<uint32_t, LogFileWriter>(source_ip, LogFileWriter(somestring+ ".log")));`

Your call to the constructor of `pair` tries to copy/move a temporary `LogFileWriter` into the `pair`. Passing the `pair` to `emplace` can't stop that happening.

You should do `mymap.emplace(source_ip, somestring+".log");`

Answer (score 3):

`std::map` is not designed to work with objects which are not copy-constructible. You have two options:

- use `std::shared_ptr<LogFileWriter>` instead of `LogFileWriter` as the map value
- use `boost::ptr_map` instead of `std::map`

If you are managing `LogFileWriter` objects with shared pointers already, you should use the first solution, otherwise use the second one.

You insert raw pointers into `boost::ptr_map` and its destructor takes care of calling `delete` for you when appropriate. Note that the `insert` method has a different signature (takes the key as the first parameter and a pointer to the value as the second one) and for some opaque reason you must provide the key as a non-const lvalue reference.

The documentation for `boost::ptr_map` is here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_map.html

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Use pointers to your objects. No need to use placement-new. The pointers are copyable, you can even manage the lifetime outside your map, and just store a vector of unique_ptr elsewhere, using raw pointers in your map.
2. Give your class a move constructor. I don't know if this is possible of course, but it might be.